# How do I apply a Isometric tile to a Diamond shaped Div

Tags: isometric, css

I want to be able to apply my isometric tile
[image]

To a diamond shaped div

However I can't seem to create the isometric shaped div.

Closest I got to it was this http://jsfiddle.net/P3yKr/2/ but even then thats not going to allow me to apply the image as the background for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leave your divs as rectangles, and simply make the corners of the image transparent. You will have to a little math when detecting clicks properly, but it will be easier in the long run.

I have created a modified version of your tile with transparency:[image: Tile with transparency]

And have made a rudimentary tiling system with this image in CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/jcpmcdonald/gMV76/20/

Alternatively, I might look into using an HTML5 game engine such as [CraftyJS](http://craftyjs.com/api/Crafty-isometric.html), or [Isogenic Game Engine](http://www.isogenicengine.com/).

Comment: That works fantastically. The only problem is the hit detection as you said. I'm unsure on how to make the divs only work for the parts of the image non-transparent. However currently that works fine.

I would use one of those engines except I have limited knowledge of HTML5 and Canvas.

Comment: I tried adding a image double the size as the last tile however it's not formatting correctly. It's still displaying white over the  new tile for some reason.

The new tile being http://i.imgur.com/rvEpfU4.png

Comment: Ahh excuse me. My mistake. I didn't set the size of the new tile correctly.